# Moving button on Online Consulting theme

Tags: css

I found a theme I really like:

https://de.wordpress.org/themes/online-consulting/

Unfortunately, the "Read more" button is in a position I don't really like:

[image]

I would vastly prefer if the button was below the post. Sadly, I'm quite unfamiliar with wordpress and don't really know where to get started.

I suppose this could be done using CSS? I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go into your Admin section, under Appearance > Edit CSS, you will be able to override the CSS of the theme. In order to find out what the class is, you might want to Inspect the control with Google Chrome's Developer Tools.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the demo for your theme, you will see those buttons are on new lines.

https://de.wordpress.org/themes/online-consulting/

It looks like it just needs to be a paragraph and then the button.  Do you maybe have the button inside the paragraph?

If you go to the demo in your browser and right click the button and select "Inspect".  You can view the demo HTML and CSS.

You can make a [child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) or save new CSS in `Appearance > Customize > Additional CSS`.

Comment: Thanks. I ill try this asap. I knew something didn't feel right about having the button on the same line as the text.